# How to submit a job to specifc nodes in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop cluster with 1 Master and 5 slaves. Is there any way of submitting jobs to specific set of slaves? Basically what i am trying to do is benchmark my application with many possibilities. So after testing with 5 slaves, I would like to run my application with 4 slaves and then 3 slaves and so on.

Currently the only way I know of is decommissioning a slave and removing from the hadoop cluster. But that seems to be a tedious task. I was wondering if there is an easier approach so as to avoid removing a node from the cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem, comments from Alex and [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774439/how-do-i-correctly-remove-nodes-in-hadoop) will help in successfully decommissioning a node from hadoop cluster.

**EDIT :** Just editing files hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml and executing `hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes` might put your datanode into decommissioning node status for a long time. So it is also necessary to change dfs.replication to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 2):

In hadoop/conf there is a file called 'slaves' here you can simply add or remove nodes, and then restart your dfs and mapred.

Comment: This answer is also useful. It kind of depends what poster wants to test - indeed, only excluding the nodes from running tasks, but not from dfs is a different situation than removing them from both dfs and mapred. The former might be faster (and without redistribution of blocks), but the latter is more accurate if you want to a scaling study.

Comment: Yes, I did consider that. But as Alex suggested, for benchmarking the system taking out hosts from slaves wont be of much help.

Comment: It does depends on what part of the system you are trying to benchmark, though. What is it your are trying to measure, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting that points to a file with a list of excluded hosts you can set in the mapred-site-xml. Though also a bit cumbersome, changing a single configuration value might be preferable physically decommissioning and recommissioning multiple nodes. You could prepare multiple host exclusion files in advance, change the setting and restart the mapreduce service. Restarting the mapreduce service is pretty quick.

[In 0.23](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/0.23.1/mapred-default.xml) this setting is named mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.exclude.filename. This is a feature introduced in 0.21, though I believe the setting was named mapred.hosts.exclude then. Check what this setting is called for the version of Hadoop you are using.

Comment: I just got to know how to decommission nodes from http://hadoop-karma.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/hadoop-cookbook-how-to-decommission.html. I didnt realize I have to edit mapred-site-xml as well. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Actually, that is an better answer than mine. The explanation is better and dfsadmin -refreshNodes is better than restarting the mapreduce service (I didn't know about this). You probably can feel confident in answering your own question with a link to the source in this situation :)

Comment: Now I am wondering how to restart name node as it is mentioned somewhere if namenode was started without the exclude file in the first place, it will throw an error. So the ideal way is to Shut down namenode, inlcude 'exclude file' and edit hdfs-site-xml and start namenode. Can you tell me how to shut it down. Do I just use service hadoop-namenode stop?

Comment: I apologize, I did not think through the blog post you linked carefully enough. It relates to excluding Data nodes, which is separate from Task trackers. Editing the mapreduce exclude file or adding one to the configuration if it does not exists, then restarting the MapReduce service should be sufficient. Restarting the name node is not necessary. What distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Hadoop 1.0.3. Anyways decommissioning datanode doesn't seem to work for me. After following the steps, when I do hadoop dfsadmin -report I still get 5 datanodes alive.

Comment: Alex, the link you provided is fro mapred-default.xml. But I have mapred-site.xml. Is there any difference in these two files. I cant find any document on mapred-site.xml for Apache hadoop 1.0.3

Comment: Yes, you are not supposed to decomission the datanodes. The task tracker, which execute the tasks of the job, and the Data Node, which holds HDFS data, are two separate services. You want to reconfigure mapred.hosts.exclude in mapred-site.xml, then restart you MapReduce service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39232/discussion-between-alex-a-and-ashwin)