# Hadoop nodes die (crash) after a while

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I have a hadoop cluster of 16 (ubuntu 12.04 server) nodes (1 master and 15 slaves). They are connected through a private network and the master also has a public IP (it belongs to two networks).
When I run small tasks, i.e., with small input and small processing time, everything works. 
However, when I run bigger tasks, i.e. with 7-8 GB of input data, my slave nodes start dying one after another.

From the web ui (`http://master:50070/dfsnodelist.jsp?whatNodes=LIVE`) I see that the last contact starts increasing and from my cluster provider's web ui, I see that the nodes have crashed. Here is the screenshot of a node (I cannot scroll up):

[image]

Another machine showed this error, with hadoop dfs running, while no job was running:

`BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 27s! [java:4072]`

and

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 41s! [java:3309]
ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0 pio 16392 in
         res 40/00:02:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Here is another screenshot (out of which I cannot make any sense):

[image]

Here is the log of a crashed datanode (with IP 192.168.0.9):

```
2014-02-01 15:17:34,874 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving blk_-2375077065158517857_1818 src: /192.168.0.7:53632 dest: /192.168.0.9:50010
2014-02-01 15:20:14,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in receiveBlock for blk_-2375077065158517857_1818 java.io.EOFException: while trying to read 65557 bytes
2014-02-01 15:20:17,556 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder blk_-2375077065158517857_1818 0 : Thread is interrupted.
2014-02-01 15:20:17,556 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for blk_-2375077065158517857_1818 terminating
2014-02-01 15:20:17,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: writeBlock blk_-2375077065158517857_1818 received exception java.io.EOFException: while trying to read 65557 bytes
2014-02-01 15:20:17,560 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.9:50010, storageID=DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
java.io.EOFException: while trying to read 65557 bytes
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.readToBuf(BlockReceiver.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.readNextPacket(BlockReceiver.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-02-01 15:21:48,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.19:60853, bytes: 132096, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000018_0_1657459557_1, offset: 0, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_-6962923875569811947_1279, duration: 276262265702
2014-02-01 15:21:56,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.19:60849, bytes: 792576, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000013_0_1311506552_1, offset: 0, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_4630218397829850426_1316, duration: 289841363522
2014-02-01 15:23:46,614 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder, call getProtocolVersion(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.InterDatanodeProtocol, 3) from 192.168.0.19:48460: output error
2014-02-01 15:23:46,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020 caught: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:265)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelWrite(Server.java:1756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2000(Server.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Responder.processResponse(Server.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Responder.doRespond(Server.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1472)
2014-02-01 15:24:26,800 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.9:36391, bytes: 10821100, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000084_0_-2100756773_1, offset: 0, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_496206494030330170_1187, duration: 439385255122
2014-02-01 15:27:11,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.20:32913, bytes: 462336, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000004_0_-1095467656_1, offset: 19968, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_-7029660283973842017_1326, duration: 205748392367
2014-02-01 15:27:57,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.9:36393, bytes: 10865080, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000033_0_-1409402881_1, offset: 0, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_-8749840347184507986_1447, duration: 649481124760
2014-02-01 15:28:47,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Verification succeeded blk_887028200097641216_1396
2014-02-01 15:30:17,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.0.9:50010, dest: /192.168.0.8:58304, bytes: 10743459, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_201402011511_0001_m_000202_0_1200991434_1, offset: 0, srvID: DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, blockid: blk_887028200097641216_1396, duration: 69130787562
2014-02-01 15:32:05,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.9:50010, storageID=DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020) Starting thread to transfer blk_-7029660283973842017_1326 to 192.168.0.8:50010
2014-02-01 15:32:55,805 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.9:50010, storageID=DS-271028747-192.168.0.9-50010-1391093674214, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020) Starting thread to transfer blk_-34479901
```

Here is how my `mapred-site.xml` files are setup:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
```

Each node has 8 CPUs and 8GB of RAM. I know that I have set `mapred.child.java.opts` too high,but with these settings and data the same jobs used to run. I have set reduce slowstart to 1.0, so reducers start only after all the mappers have finished.

Pinging some nodes results in a small percentage of packets lost and ssh connection freezes for a while, but I don't know if it is relevant. I have added to the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file on each node the line:

`hadoop           hard    nofile          16384`

but that didn't work either.

**SOLUTION**: It seems that after all, it was a memory error, indeed. I had too many running tasks and the computers crashed. After they crashed and I rebooted them, the hadoop jobs did not run correclty, even if I set the correct number of mappers. The solution was to remove bad datanodes (through decommissioning) and then include them again. Here is what I did and everything worked perfectly again, without losing any data:

[How do I correctly remove nodes in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774439/how-do-i-correctly-remove-nodes-in-hadoop)

And of course, set the right number of max map and reduce tasks per node.

Comment: The stacktrace contains memory related info, so maybe you're running out of memory there. You could for example use 'free' in a loop to see if the memory consumption goes out of hand on the nodes during computation.

Comment: @TeTeT I think it's not a memory error. Running `free`, while the machine fails to respond to master, I see that only 50% or less of memory is used. (I changed the settings, so that less memory will be used, but the problem stil exists). Could it be a network error?

Comment: In the reduce phase, copying seems to occur at 0.33 MB/s!!!

Comment: While testing my network speed with `iperf`, I see speeds of 6.43 Gbits/sec!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you're running out of memory as per mapped u have 2GB RAM and 4 maps are allowed.

Please try to run the same job with 1 GB xmx it will surely work out.

If u wanna use your cluster efficiently set the xmx according to block size of files.

If your block is of 128 Mb then 512 mb is sufficient.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work (java heap was not sufficient). 1GB is not enough, because I keep some combinations of input in memory. Also, the same programs, with the same settings and same input, used to run before. I also tried with fewer maps, but still got the same error.

Comment: Can we reduce the no of map task to 2?

Comment: What is the block size and replication factor?

Comment: Block size is default (64MB) and replication factor is 3.

Comment: It looks good... Does All the slaves have datanode as well as task tracker?

Comment: Yes. All 15 slaves are datanodes and tasktrackers. I am starting to believe that this is a hardware error, but I don't know for sure

Comment: Yeah it may be but if you  take my advice try to debug the problem using back tracking or do one thing increase the block size and replication factor see what happens...

Comment: The problem is still unsolved, but I am awarding you the bounty, before it expires, for the time that you spent trying to help. That was the reason of the bounty after all, to get some attention. Thanks!

Comment: thanks i appreciate your thinking and just another thought came in my mind that check for the ulimit from here http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html that might be the problem and once again thanks :)

Comment: I have already set that to 16384, as described in my question.

Answer (score 3):

does the job have a combiner step between M and R? I have had a problem with high mem Map and Combine steps happening at the same time on same nodes in tasks that take a lot of memory. With your config if 2 maps and 2 combines are happening you could be using 8G ram if you have large objects in memory. just a thought.

Comment: good point, but the problem (long response time) also appears when i simply start the datanode and no jobs are running, and it also exists in both jobs with and without a combiner

Comment: One time I had a problem with a virus scanner / security software (linux shield) that was installed on the nodes...have you watched the nodes with something like  htop to see what other procs are running as they go down